# HP Mini 1000 Horrible Echo

Tags: microphone, echo, hp-mini

EDIT:

OS is Windows XP Home Premium SP2. The echo only seems to happen when using Adobe Flash...hmph, just another reason to hate Flash. Recording seems fine with WAV files, as well as Skype, but a Flash application causes this echo.

---

I was given this HP Mini a few days ago, and it's been great so far, except when I try to video chat.

The slightest sound recorded into the mic echos many times, each time louder than the last.

This happens through Adobe Flash via Google Chrome, if that means anything.

I've tried adjusting the recording volume but still no luck...any ideas?

Comment: Try adjust the PLAYBACK volume (downwards), and use headphones (if you arn't already) to cut out/down the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows 7 or similar modern version of Windows.)

Go to the control panel, sound, recording tab. Find "listen to this device", make sure it's unchecked and click apply or ok. Also look for options/recording devices for recording the outgoing audio, and make sure they are unchecked/that this recording device is not select as default.